# LibreOffice Writer: Forms are not editable after save

Tags: libreoffice-writer, forms

after creating an odt document which has form controls (textbox, checkbox etc), I cannot edit the forms when I open the document again.
You have to select everything and copy it in a new document. But all the formatted paragraphs are gone and you have to do it again.

What have I to do so that it is editable after opening the document again? 
Or how can I also copy the formatting and not just the content?

I am using:
Ubuntu 12.04 LTS with LibreOffice 3.5.7.2
 and
Mint 17 with LibreOffice 4.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with a LibreOffice  Writer Form, there are two modes:

- Design mode On: Edit / modify the form controls;
- Design mode off: Use the form.

On opening a LO Writer Form document, **design mode is off by default**. To toggle between design mode on/off, you'll have to enable either the "`Form Design`" toolbar or the "`Form Controls`" toolbar (Menu "`View`" -> "`Toolbars`"):

[image]

Now, you can toggle design mode using the second button in one of those toolbars:

[image]

In OpenOffice.org Writer, the icons may look different - see [this wiki page](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/OOoAuthors_User_Manual/Writer_Guide/Creating_a_simple_form) and the following screenshot from the OOo Wiki:

[image]